# Recurrence relation for polygamma reflection polynomials

Tags: special-functions, recurrence-relations, polygamma

In the reflection formula for the polygamma function
$$
\psi^{(n)}(1-z) + (-1)^{n+1}\psi^{(n)}(z) %
= (-1)^{n} \pi \frac{d^{n}}{d z^{n}} \cot (\pi z)
$$
the right hand side is a polynomial $(-1)^{n}\pi^{n+1} P_{n+1}(\cot \pi z)$. With 
$x=\cot \pi z$, the first few polynomials are:
$$
x\\
-x^2-1\\
2 x^3 + 2 x\\
-6 x^4 - 8 x^2 - 2\\
24 x^5 +40 x^3 + 16 x\\
-120 x^6-240 x^4-136 x^2-16\\
$$
For a numerical library function I have already computed and stored coefficients 
up to $n=12$. The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma#Reflection_relation) article gives a recursion formula for 
(slightly different) $P_{n+1}$ in terms of $P_n$ and $P_n'$. 
Now my **question**: Is there a known recurrence formula for computing 
the values $P_n(x)$ of the form like those for orthogonal polynomials
\begin{align}
P_n(a) &= a(n,x) P_{n-1}(x) + b(n,x) P_{n-2}(x), \quad\text{or maybe}\\
P_n(a) &= a(n,x) P_{n-1}(x) + b(n,x) P_{n-2}(x)+ c(n,x) P_{n-3}(x)
\end{align}
with (relative) simple expressions $a, b, c$? I do not want to compute
and cache the coefficients for higher degrees; and I am open to 
other or better **numerical** algorithms.